# ¿Cómo puedo realizar un informe de dos páginas en Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft

Debo realizar un reporte con la siguiente estructura utilizando Jasper Reports

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El reporte se encuentra dividido en dos páginas tamaño carta o A4 pero en Jasper Reports no me permite realizarlo en dos páginas, realizo todo el proceso en el apartado de details pero se muestra en una segunda página y en la primera página me aparece el titulo y lo demás en blanco. Si realizo todo en el column header no alcanzo a colocar todos los elementos que necesito en mi reporte y lo que alcanzo a colocar se repite en las paginas 1 y 2.

He buscado por internet como solucionarlo pero solo encuentro como realizar tablas dinámicas y no logró encontrar nada cercano a lo que estoy buscando.

¿Alguien sabe acerca de como generar un reporte en dos páginas sin que le suceda lo mismo que a mi?